# Inserting variable into sql string variable

Tags: php, sql-server

```
$sql = "insert into dbo.".$st_tab." (bike_id,st_id";
        if($st_tab === "st1_rec_id"||$st_tab === "st2_rec_id"||$st_tab ==="st3_rec_id")
        {
            $sql .= ",ln_id";
        }
        $sql .= ",times,date) values (?,?";
        if($st_tab === "st1_rec_id"||$st_tab === "st2_rec_id"||$st_tab ==="st3_rec_id")
        {
            $sql .= ",?";
        }
        $sql .= ",?,?)";
        echo $sql;
        if($st_tab === "st1_rec_id"||$st_tab === "st2_rec_id"||$st_tab ==="st3_rec_id")
        {
            $var = array($bike_id,$station,$line,$time,$date);
        }
        else
        {
            $var = array($bike_id,$station,$station,$time,$date);
        }
        $insert = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql,$var);
        if($insert === false)
        {
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
        }
        else
        {
            foreach($var as $x => $a)
            {
                echo $x." : ".$a." ";
            }
            echo "<br> 1 Record Added";
        }
```

due that code I got an query error

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102
>   [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near 'chs_st2_rec'. [message] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax
>   near 'chs_st2_rec'. ) )

I can't identify what's error and where it's.

Comment: i've try to print out assembled SQL string after "$sql .= ",?,?)";" 
i've echo $sql but it's didn't show.

thanks

Comment: Figure out what's actually going on. If you can't print out the SQL string even, then this isn't the right code excerpt. (Notably there's no `chs_st2_rec` to be seen; yet that's what the error message is about). If this isn't actually the relevant code, you won't get it answered. Please invest a bit more time in adding details (See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [Writing the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), or [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)…)

Comment: ah i've got it it's my fault 
the code error before this code and i get this done 
i've edit **
$sql = "select '$st_char'
            from '$st_tab'
            where bike_id like '$bike_id'"; ** into 
**$sql = "select $st_char
            from $st_tab
            where bike_id like '$bike_id'"; ** and that's work :) . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out

the code error before all of these line

reason is i used single quotes with variable

```
$sql = "select '$st_char'
            from '$st_tab'
            where bike_id like '$bike_id'";
```

so i remove single quotes out and it's work

thanks everyone :)